io.mock.verify does watch wrong queue name
I am sending a msg into my own program by sending it into the incoming sqs queue and then I am trying to check with a verify if my program made a call to a given outgoing queue at the end of it by calling
verify(atLeast = 1) { sqsTemplate.send("some-queue-out", any<Array<OutMessage>>()) }

but I am running into the error msg:
java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion condition Verification failed: call 1 of 1: SqsTemplate(sqsTemplate#26).send(eq(some-queue-out), any())). Only one matching call to SqsTemplate(sqsTemplate#26)/send(String, Any) happened, but arguments are not matching:[0]: argument: some-queue-name, matcher: eq(some-queue-out), result: -

where...
some-queue-name is my incoming queue
some-queue-out is my outgoing queue
I just can't make up my mind why my incomming queue is in the error msg, when i never called for it in the verify
initially i was loading the data in from a yaml file, but inputing the name by hand does not change a thing
what does make the test succeed is, when calling "some-queue-name"(the incomming queue), but that is not what i want to check
I run a spring project(3.2.1) with gradle and kotlin(jvm21)

Sounds a lot like something other code is invoking sqsTemplate.send.  I'd put a breakpoint on the AssertionError and the walk back in the stack trace to find what is invoking the mock.

The error is telling you that while you expect the call to be made with "some-queue-out", it was actually made with "some-queue-name".  Meaning that in your code, you are calling that method with the argument of "some-queue-name".  Show your code that is doing the send.

@AndrewL thanks mate, sorry for the delay, i will try this out tomorrow, tinker around with that idea and come back to you!

@lane.maxwell
first i am sending a msg to my in-queue through my TestUtils.class by calling:
sqsTemplate.send(<yaml-file>.queueIn, arrayOf(inMessage))
and later in my "production-code" i try to send it to the out-queue by calling:
sqsTemplate.send(<yaml-file>.queueOut, versions.toTypedArray<OutMessage>())
also when i call sqsTemplate.receiveMany{it.queue(mediaManagerProperties.queueOut)} instead i always find messages on the out-queue,should this be possible when the verify fails?
the  is the same for both,the only difference being the different queues i am calling

I think it would be clearer it you update your original post with the code from the main code and the test code.
